# closing mongodb native nodejs connection with pooling

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Based upon the docs it seem to be that mongodb connections should be pooled by creating a single connection at the start of the app and then just using that connection throughout the lifetime of the app.

However I was wondering if the mongodb connection should be manually cleaned up some way once the app closes or should it just automatically clean itself up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connection pooling is something the driver does internally to make client-MongoDB communication more efficient when handling lots of requests over an extended period of time. Connections are used and returned to a pool to be used again. You should generally have one `MongoClient` per application (i.e. you should have one unless you have a specific reason for needing more than one) and your application should call the `.close()` method on the client when the application shuts down.